# Requests with 'posse'

Tags: classical-latin, roman-culture, semantics, politeness

In English and many other languages, asking "can you close the window?" is not an inquiry on the ability to close the window but rather a request to do so.
Can the (classical) Latin *posse* be used the same way?
I looked at [the Lewis & Short entry on *posse*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=possum&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) and found no trace of such use.

I believe that, even if possible, this is not the most idiomatic request.
I would rather say *fac fenestram claudas* or *claude fenestram, quaeso*.
The question is whether a Roman would understand *potesne fenestram claudere?* as a request and whether there are any such uses is extant literature.
Expressing requests as ability questions is a cultural matter, and the Roman culture may have been different from ours in this respect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Questions" that are actually requests using the archaic ["potin?"](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23potin%23) are numerous in Plautus, and they appear in Terence as well. I think based on the evidence that a Roman would readily understand this type of request-phrased-as-a-question but might find it somewhat rude or abrupt: the examples in the corpus always seem to carry a hint of exasperation.

Plautus *Poenulus* 916

> Latin: 
>   **M:** Potin ut taceas? **S:** Taceo atque abeo.
>
> English:
>   **M:** Can you be quiet? **S:** I'm quiet and I'm leaving!

Terence *Adelphoe* 539

> Latin: 
>   **C.** siquid rogabit, nusquam tu me: audistin? **S.** potin ut desinas?
>
> English:
>   **C.** If he asks, you haven't seen me anywhere: understand? **S.** Can you
>   let it go?! *(i.e. I get it already!)*

Comment: Note that the regular [**potesne**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=la&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3AGreco-Roman&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3AArabic&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3AGermanic&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3Acwar&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3ARenaissance&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3ARichTimes&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3APDILL&all_words=potesne&phrase=&any_words=&exclude_words=&search=Search) is also attested a number of times (in Cicero, Livy, Seneca, etc.)

Comment: “potesne” appears 10 time in the corpus, but in all authors (except Plautus) it is being used as an actual question (“are you able to?”), not a veiled request.